# condition on model on class macros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-ferret

It's possible to put conditions on models like:

```
class MyPeppers < ActiveRecord::Base
   acts_as_a_ferret() if Rails.env.production?
end
```

It's valid ruby code but I wonder if that should work?

Comment: should work just fine

Comment: This question isn't structured in a way that we can provide you with much help. Did you try this code out before asking the question? Are you running into errors when you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will work because it is a perfectly valid Ruby code.